# Texture no longer renders after UV change

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures, uv-mapping

I'm going to write a texture atlas manager, but I've run into a problem. When I modified my original UV coordinates, my program no longer rendered anything?? This is my draw code:

```
- (void)drawFrame {
[(EAGLView *)self.view setFramebuffer];

//GLfloat aspectRatio = self.view.bounds.size.height/self.view.bounds.size.width; 
float m[16] = {2/self.view.bounds.size.width, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2/self.view.bounds.size.height, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };

CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(512, 512);
CGRect drawBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 106, 126);

GLfloat x = (1/imageSize.width) * drawBounds.size.width;
GLfloat y = (1/imageSize.height) * drawBounds.size.height;

static const GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -53.0f, -63.0f,
    53.0f, -63.0f,
    -53.0f,  63.0f,
    53.0f,  63.0f,
};

GLfloat texCoords[] = {
    0.0, 0.0,
    x, 0.0,
    0.0, y,
    x, y
};

glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(program);

[[TextureLibrary sharedTextureLibrary] bindTexture:@"bounce" toSlot:GL_TEXTURE0];

glUniform1f(uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE], 0);
glUniformMatrix4fv(UNIFORM_MVP_MATRIX, 1, GL_FALSE, m);

glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, vertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXTURE_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, texCoords);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXTURE_POSITION);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);


[(EAGLView *)self.view presentFramebuffer];
}
```

However, it works fine like this:

```
GLfloat texCoords[] = {
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0
};
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but OpenGL considers (0, 0) to be the lower left corner of an image. Is it possible your graphic is in the top left, so that the area you're displaying is actually from a transparent part of the texture?

If so then you can either adjust your texture coordinates or adjust the texture matrix stack so that (0, 0) is in the top left.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a total newb to OpenGL. How might I do that in ES 2.0?

Comment: The easiest solution is either to convert all your 't' coordinates (the y coordinates in texture space) from t to 1.0 - t. So you'd be storing `1.0` and `1.0 - y` rather than `0.0` and `y` in your code. Alternatively do the conversion in your vertex shader. The old fixed functionality applied a matrix transform to texture coordinates, which is also useful for purposes like data size reduction (e.g. to store your coordinates as bytes, so you can scale those 0 to 255 inputs to the range you're interested in), but obviously you can do whatever you think is appropriate.